# How to make ldap return only cn

Tags: shell, ldap, sh, distinguishedname

I want to let ldap search accounts starting with z and then show only cn's (without "cn:") in reverse alphabetical order, and not case-sensitive. Also I'm trying to remove empty lines between cn's. 
Here's my script now. Stuck on it

```
ldapsearch -o ldif-wrap=no -L "(uid=z*)" cn | grep '^cn:'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution

```
ldapsearch -x -L "(uid=z*)" cn | grep '^cn:' | sort -r --ignore-case | cut -c5-999
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -S [-]attribute.
[-] stands for reverse order